# Update the coordinates and center map to marker

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have a Google Maps JavaScript v3 map on my website that allows me to drag the marker to get the coordinates for the given location. This works perfectly but I also want to enter the coordinates manually and then click on a link to update the marker. This works great but I can't center the map to the marker (make it to pan to the marker).

I have also added a select box with solid coordinates to quickly get to a specific location on the map. I have the same problem for this one to as for the first problem.

The problem is that when I manually enter the coordinates or choose a fixed location, the marker only moves few steps from the origin position or it doesn't move at all. When you try to grab the marker and move it you can't move it and the X is far away from the marker. After few attempts to move the marker the maps goes blank but the marker stands still.

You can see my solution and problems on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/edgren/PaTQq/). How can I fix my issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 function moveMarker() {
    var lat = parseFloat(document.getElementById('marker-latitude').value);
    var lng = parseFloat(document.getElementById('marker-longitude').value);
    var newLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

    marker.setPosition(newLatLng);
    map.setCenter(newLatLng);
}
```

Does that work?

Comment: So you must have 2 textfields for each coordinate? Ok. But how can I fix the problem with the coordinates in the select box?

Comment: Nevermind! I fixed that issue with `split`. Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Not a problem Erik, sorry just got your message.